# Problems with ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to build an app to translate English into pig latin. But before I do the conditional coding for it I want it to print what I have on screen. It only prints the last word on the screen. Eg if I type This is the words it types words. I am guessing it is because I am not using an index but I have no clue. I am a beginner programmer and I need help. This is my Java Code.

```
package com.example.morna.piglatin;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickTranslate(View v)
    {
        final String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        EditText inputTranslateText =      (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edEnglishText);
        String t = inputTranslateText.getText().toString();
        List <String> objects = Arrays.asList(t.split("\\s+"));



        for(String object: objects)
        {
            TextView outputPigLatin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPigLatin);
            outputPigLatin.setText(String.valueOf(object));

        }
```

Comment: Try to replace the last line with this: outputPigLatin.setText(outputPigLatin.getText()+" "+String.valueOf(object));

Comment: you call setText for the same TextView multiple times ... every call replaces the previous value so after the loop finishes you only see the last word of your list

Comment: print your text get from mEditText.

Answer (score 1):

It's because with every iteration of loop you set new text into `textView`, so old text is overridden by a new one from a loop, moreover you declare `textView` many times in a loop, it's pointless and not optimal, so it will be slow.
Instead of this code:

```
for(String object: objects)
{
    TextView outputPigLatin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPigLatin);
    outputPigLatin.setText(String.valueOf(object));

}
```

Use this one, put `TextView` outside loop, and set text only once outside loop too:

```
TextView outputPigLatin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPigLatin);
String myText = null;
for(String object: objects)
{
    myText += object+", ";

}
outputPigLatin.setText(myText);
```

If you have a lot of words to print (like hundred or thousands), more optimal approach will be use of `StringBuilder` class:

```
TextView outputPigLatin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPigLatin);
StringBuilder myText = new StringBuilder();
for(String object: objects)
{
    myText.append(object).append(", ");

}
outputPigLatin.setText(myText.toString());
```